# how to exit react native app when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, react-native

I am devloping a mobile app using react native and i want to exit the app after clicking a button.

My scenario is that if the user has not verified his/her email after certains days i will prompt the user an [Alert Dialog](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.39/docs/alert.html#alert) every the time the app is opened blocking the app usage until the user email is verified.

So after the users click OK, how do I exit the app programmatically?

Comment: You can use this packages for exit on double back https://github.com/rgabs/exit-on-double-back

Answer (score 7):

```
import BackHandler from 'react-native';
// Note: work only on Android
    BackHandler.exitApp();
```

Answer (score 6):

For `iOS`, you can use the following library: https://github.com/wumke/react-native-exit-app. It uses native library to exit the app programmatically. You can exit the app using:

```
RNExitApp.exitApp()
```

For `android`, you can use `BackAndroid` from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backandroid.html

```
BackAndroid.exitApp()
```

Comment: BackAndroid is deprecated. Use BackHandler instead.

Comment: @NirLevy The author updated the licence to a more permissive MIT licence :)

Answer (score 4):

Apple would reject your iOS app if you exit the app on button click. You could just show an alert without a button. User won't be able to dismiss the alert and enter the app rendering it useless.

Comment: your solution makes sense but the issue is that Alerts cannot be displayed without buttons in react native. By default a button is included and there is no way to hide it base on what i have read so far. do you know how to show an alert without buttons?

Answer (score 3):

[BackAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler#exitapp) should be able to help you. Use [Alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html) callback to use `BackHandler`

```
var {
  Alert,
  BackHandler,
} = ReactNative;



Alert.alert(
            'Alert Title',
            alertMessage,
            [
              {text: 'OK', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
            ]
);
```

Comment: Should this be used with platform check? BackAndroid wont work for iOS!

Comment: `BackHandler.exitApp()` is exit only current screen. how to exit from application and clear the stack.

Comment: BackHandler.exitApp() work both for android and ios.

Comment: @Moein No, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

```
<Text style = {something}
        onPress ={
        ()=>{
        console.log('clicked');
        return BackHandler.exitApp();
        }
        }>Exit</Text>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exitApp()` method from `BackHandler` class to exit your app in android.

```
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, BackHandler } from 'react-native';

class Scan extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> BackHandler.exitApp()}>
                    <Text>Quit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```